# Why are w8,w9 used instead of w1,w2?

Tags: c, arm

I am studying about armv8.
The following c language code
When converted to assembly with clang, w0 seems to be used for the return value, and w8 and w9 are used to save the variable values.
It is said that the arm has w series registers w0 to w30, but why are w8 and w9 used instead of w1 and w2?

```c
int main() {
    int a = 3;
    int b = 5;
    int c = a + b;
    return c;
}
```

```
main:                                   // @main
        sub     sp, sp, #16                     // =16
        str     wzr, [sp, #12]
        mov     w8, #3
        str     w8, [sp, #8]
        mov     w8, #5
        str     w8, [sp, #4]
        ldr     w8, [sp, #8]
        ldr     w9, [sp, #4]
        add     w8, w8, w9
        str     w8, [sp]
        ldr     w0, [sp]
        add     sp, sp, #16                     // =16
        ret
```

Comment: Perhaps the [ABI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface) requires the use of certain registers for certain things?

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/arm64-windows-abi-conventions?view=msvc-170 - x0/w0 is the return value, x0/w0-x7/w7 are used for function arguments, x8/w8 through x15/w15 are scratch registers, etc.

Comment: thank you for your reply.
This is the first time I've heard of ABI.
w1-w7 are used to pass parameters.
Thank you for your precious time!